# Will upgrade to SSD guarantee zero Application Not Responding Errors?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, visual-studio-2022

I am very much aware that Visual Studio 2022 is a very heavy IDE software and was optimized for Solid State Drives. My system is running a `core i5-7200u` and a `500 GB hard drive Western Digital.` So yesterday I happened to run it alongside other 6 programs and I kept getting Application Not Responding warnings which were related to the Hard Drive's  **Read and Write Speeds** that is according to the red highlights on the disk section on the **Task Manager** control panel. So as I was planning to get a new Solid State Drive for this system so heavy programs am running like **Android Studio** and **R Studio** wouldn't take forever to read and write to and from the drive, I noticed that today it is not throwing Application Not Responding from the Hard Drive Buffer  because I am not running very many Hard Drive intensive tasks, My 8 Gigs RAM is pretty fast because it is of DDR4 type, my question is, is this Hard Drive a potential bottleneck to this processor and if yes will the upgrade guarantee me **Zero Application Not Responding Warnings incidences** provided the RAM usage stays within the allowed limits ?, Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will upgrade to SSD guarantee zero Application Not Responding Errors?

No. While slow I/O can contribute to these errors, there are more reasons why they could appear.

Still, it's worth getting an SSD because the system will feel much, much more responsive.

That being said, 8 GB of RAM is bare minimum these days even for light Internet browsing, not to mention development and running heavy IDEs. When the RAM gets scarce the system will start moving less frequently used data to the HDD/SSD. At this point the speed of RAM doesn't matter because even fastest SSDs are orders of magnitude slower than RAM and that becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

> But if the main causes of Application Not Responding is the I/O then a faster SSD should fix that permanently , suppose I run 32 Gigs of RAM does that mean I can run like 30 programs at the same time without any lagging or throwing ANR?

No. When increasing the load of your machine by increasing the number of programs running in parallel I guarantee you that you will face a bottleneck.

The issue is to mitigate bottlenecks. The mitigation process is not limited to the increase of RAM or using a SSD.
It could involve using a couple of SSDs, installing programs differently and may involve your user behaviour.

> guarantee me Zero Application Not Responding Warnings incidences

Binary requirements are not useful in your case.

Avoid thrashing at all cost!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by my user behavior?, downloading junk from the internet? lol

Comment: Correct. "Downloading junk" puts a load on your drive. Equalize load over time and ressources.

Comment: I noticed a hard drive with more free space is faster than a hard drive that is filled up, why is this?